# Wordpress category list of any parent category

Tags: wordpress, categories

i want to show list of child categories of Blog category. how do i do that?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code which will display child categories of the current post:

```
$category=get_the_category();
$parent_id = $category[0]->cat_ID;

foreach($category as $childcat) 
{
  if (cat_is_ancestor_of($parent_id, $childcat)) 
  {
    echo $childcat->cat_name;
  }
}
```

Put it inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`wp_list_categories()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_categories) with the `child_of` parameter set to the ID of the parent category.